# No puedo Parser Retrofit

Tags: android-studio, json, parsear

Hola a Todos estoy intentando leer un archivo json con retrofit para luego guardarlo en sqllite, pero al implementar el proyecto la app se cierra

Tengo la clase Clientes, son más campos pero asi va la estructura, con sus set a get respectivo.

```
@SerializedName("CMA_CODIGO")
@Expose
private String cMACODIGO;
@SerializedName("CMA_TIPO_CLIENTE")
@Expose
private String cMATIPOCLIENTE;
@SerializedName("CMA_NOMBRE")
@Expose
private String cMANOMBRE;
```

La interface está asi.

```
public interface RetrofitClientesArray {
/*
    * Retrofit get annotation with our URL
    * And our method that will return us details of student.
   */
@GET("cspm/clientes.json")
Call<List<clientes>> getClientesDetails();
```

}

En el main esta la funcion para leer así.

```
private  void getRetrofitClientes(){
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://tucuenca.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

            RetrofitClientesArray service = retrofit.create(RetrofitClientesArray.class);
            Call<List<clientes>> call = service.getClientesDetails();

            call.enqueue(new Callback<List<clientes>>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<List<clientes>> call, Response<List<clientes>> response) {

                    try{
                        Log.d("Exito ", "Leyendo");
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        Log.d("onResponse", "There is an error");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<List<clientes>> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.d("onFailure", t.toString());
                    showLoginError(t.toString());
                }
            });
    }
```

Al ejecutar el logcat me da este mensaje

> ```
> 04-19 13:12:59.778 32209-32209/com.---.ventas3.spm I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni 04-19 13:12:59.778
> ```
>
> 32209-32209/com.---.ventas3.spm I/art: Reinit property:
>   dalvik.vm.checkjni= false 04-19 13:12:59.907 32209-32209/? W/System:
>   ClassLoader referenced unknown path:
>   /data/app/com.---.ventas3.spm-2/lib/arm64 04-19 13:12:59.908
>   32209-32209/? W/art: JIT profile information will not be recorded:
>   profile file does not exits. 04-19 13:12:59.915 32209-32209/?
>   I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process 04-19
>   13:12:59.934 32209-32209/? I/HwCust: Constructor found for class
>   android.app.HwCustActivityImpl 04-19 13:12:59.948 32209-32209/?
>   I/HwCust: Constructor found for class
>   android.app.HwCustHwWallpaperManagerImpl 04-19 13:12:59.961
>   32209-32209/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method
>   android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter
>   android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter,
>   android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode)
>   would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable 04-19 13:13:00.142 32209-32209/?
>   I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null 04-19
>   13:13:00.145 32209-32209/? I/HwPointEventFilter: support AFT 04-19
>   13:13:00.154 32209-32271/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 32209 SIG:
>   9

Comment: Estas cargando un gráfico .xml de un .svg en alguna parte?

Comment: me parece que este error es en el layout, te recomendaría lo agregaras, particularmente donde aplicas tinte!